# $_POST is empty after making a post request from android

Tags: php, android, httprequest

I am trying to login system with android and php. I can read response from the url but the $_POST array is always empty.I am new at this so any help will be appreciated.Here is my android code.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     
        try {
            String link="http://10.0.2.2/monitorhealth";

            HttpClient httpClinet=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(link);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","X"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","Y"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response=httpClinet.execute(httppost);

            InputStream inputStream=response.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line);

            }
            Log.e("Response","Received:"+sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
}
```

In the index.php there is only one statement $_POST['username] which shows an error.

Comment: can you show us the contents of index.php?

Comment: <?php
echo $_POST['username']." ".$_POST['password'];
?>

Answer (score 0):

found the error.Just had to correct the url. Replaced it with

```
<code>
String link="http://10.0.2.2/monitorhealth/index.php";
</code>
```